# Skype link and HTML encoding?

Tags: html, skype

I'm trying to get Skype button to work from here: http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/

But I'm having problems with Skype names in href, which contains from 3 words and its like: 
"**Word1 word2 - word3**". That generator creates link like:

```
<a href="skype:word1 word2 - word3?call"><img src="http://mystatus.skype.com/bigclassic/word1 word2 - word3" style="border: none;" width="182" height="44" alt="My status" /></a>
```

If I click on this link, Skype calls 3 names?!

What should be between words, tried with %20 but nothing?

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

Sorry guys... clients... ehm, they gave me that Username, but its not, its with dots :\
Im not using Skype so i didnt know

Sorry one more time, and thanks

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be a `+`. This is what is most commonly used on mailing lists and such. Other separators to try would be `_` and `-`, but `+` is the most likely one.